# How to fixing deprecated classes in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, deprecated, fixed

I have an old Flutter project which was made on flutter 1.22.5, since I updated my flutter to 2.. many classes like FlatButton have been deprecated. Is there any shortcut to convert all the deprecated Classes to the updated ones?

Answer (score 1):

Flutter Fix

> The Flutter Fix feature, introduced in Flutter 2, combines a Dart command-line tool with changes suggested by the Dart analyzer to automatically clean up deprecated APIs in your codebase.

> This feature has also been added to IDE plugins for Flutter (2.0) and Dart (2.12). Depending on the IDE, these automated updates are called quick-fixes (IntelliJ, Android Studio, Eclipse) or code actions (VS Code).

https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/flutter-fix

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no shortcut of it, as far as I know, you have to change them as condition required